# Why does Sir Harry like Matthias's poem and not Basil's?

Tags: poetry, character-analysis, brian-jacques, redwall-series

In [*Mattimeo*](https://redwall.fandom.com/wiki/Mattimeo_(book)), Chapter 29, the rescuers' party encounters [Sir Harry](https://redwall.fandom.com/wiki/Sir_Harry_the_Muse), an owl who speaks in poetry for much of his dialogue. For one example, this is how he introduces himself:

> "Why, pray, do you suppose?
> I'm master of poetry and prose,
> No equal have I in field or wood,
> No creature a smidgeon, a fraction as good.
> And if you need a poet, why, here's one to choose,
> This Owl. . . . Sir Harry the Muse."

Both Matthias and Basil Stag Hare try to impress Sir Harry. Here is Matthias's attempt:

> "Business for goodness sake,
> Perhaps we can find some cake.
> Maybe, my friend, we will bring to you
> A shrewcake baked by a shrew."
>
> At first Sir Harry looked undecided, then he stamped his talons and clacked his hooded beak in approval.
>
> "Not bad, not bad at all.
> At least it made me smile.
> For a Warrior, I'd say quite good,
> You have a certain style."

It appears that Sir Harry approves of Matthias's poem. However, the owl's opinion of Basil's poetry is just about the opposite.

> "I beg you to listen to me,
> I'm a fellow spirit, you see.
> I was once considered a champion poet.
> I just thought you'd like to know it. . . ."
>
> Cheek tittered and avoided Basil's paw in the same instant.
> Sir Harry turned his back and delivered a cutting line:
>
> "I beg, I implore you, sir,
> Stick to being a hare!"

Why is there such a difference in Sir Harry's reaction to these two poems? Note that I have tagged this [character-analysis](/questions/tagged/character-analysis); I'm not looking for just an analysis of the poems, but an analysis of how *Sir Harry* would have analyzed the poems, and the reasoning behind his opinions of them.

Comment: One possibility: Basil's poem claims that Basil is a champion poet, setting him up as a rival to Sir Harry. And of course, this offends Sir Harry's ego. I haven't read the book, so I don't know whether this is in accord with how Sir Harry is depicted, but it seems possible from the short quotes in your question.